# How to divide list with help awk

Tags: bash

i need help. I have file vm.list:

```
VM-NAME1|WEEKDAY|2|
VM-NAME2|WEEKDAY|4|
VM-NAME3|WEEKDAY|3|
VM-NAME4|WEEKDAY|4|
VM-NAME5|WEEKDAY|4|
VM-NAME6|WEEKDAY|1|
VM-NAME7|WEEKDAY|1|
VM-NAME8|WEEKDAY|4|
VM-NAME9|WEEKDAY|2|
VM-NAME10|WEEKDAY|4|
VM-NAME11|WEEKDAY|4|
```

I need list divide into new lists depending of 3 value and action run:

```
LIST1:
VM-NAME6
VM-NAME7

LIST2:
VM-NAME1
VM-NAME9

LIST3:
VM-NAME3

LIST4:
VM-NAME2
VM-NAME4
VM-NAME5
VM-NAME8
VM-NAME10
VM-NAME11
```

Just about it

```
for i in $(awk -F "|" '{print $3}' today.list | sort | uniq)
    do echo $i
    awk -F "|" '{ if ($3 == '$i') print $1 }' today.list
done
```

i understand what it incorrect, but i don't have ideas

Answer (score 4, accepted):

give this awk one-liner a try:

```
awk -F'|' '{a[$3]=a[$3]RS$1}END{for(x in a)print "List"x":" a[x]}' file
```

Comment: Cool :) This won't sort the output though.

Comment: @Nikita : In fact,it can't be any better than this. :)

Answer (score 0):

A version that expects the source file being in order by cols 3 and 1 (handled by `sort` in process substitution).

```
$ awk -F\| '{ print q ($3!=p?ORS "LIST" $3 ":":"") }{ p=$3; q=$1 }' <(sort -t\| -k3 -k1 file)

LIST1:
VM-NAME6
VM-NAME7
LIST2:
VM-NAME1
VM-NAME9
LIST3:
VM-NAME3
LIST4:
VM-NAME10
VM-NAME11
VM-NAME2
VM-NAME4
VM-NAME5
```

It won't store the whole record set in memory.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the output in separate files, named `List{1..4}`, you can use this:

```
$ awk -F'|' '{print $1 > "List" $3}' vm.list

$ head -n100 List* # just a quick hack to print them with a header...
==> List1 <==
VM-NAME6
VM-NAME7

==> List2 <==
VM-NAME1
VM-NAME9

==> List3 <==
VM-NAME3

==> List4 <==
VM-NAME2
VM-NAME4
VM-NAME5
VM-NAME8
VM-NAME10
VM-NAME11
```